# How to fix "The getter 'controller' isn't defined" error in Flutter's AllTasks class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter application:

```
lib/screens/all_tasks.dart:141:27: Error: The getter 'controller' isn't defined for the class 'AllTasks'.
 - 'AllTasks' is from 'package:flutter_golang_yt/screens/all_tasks.dart' ('lib/screens/all_tasks.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'controller'.
                    text: controller.myData[index]["task_name"],
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that the error indicates the `controller` variable is not defined within the `AllTasks` class. I'm following a tutorial where the instructor uses `controller` without issue, and I'm unsure why it's failing for me.

**Here's the relevant portion of my `all_tasks.dart` file:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_golang_yt/controllers/data_controller.dart';
// ... other imports

class AllTasks extends StatelessWidget {
  const AllTasks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // ... other methods 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ... other code

    return Scaffold(
      // ... other code

      body: Column(
        children: [
          // ... other widgets

          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: myData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Dismissible( 
                  // ... other code

                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10),
                    child: TaskWidget(
                      text: controller.myData[index]["task_name"], // <-- Problem line
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I suspect I might be missing a setup step or a dependency.  Can anyone help me understand how to properly use and access the `controller` within my `AllTasks` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [GetxBindings](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/dependency-management/binding/), you can make your widget inherit from `GetView`, as the example below:

```dart
class AllTasks extends GetView<DataController> {
...
```

If you don't, you should store the response from `Get.find<DataController>()` in a variable called `controller`.

```dart
class AllTasks extends StatelessWidget {
  late final DataController controller;
  const AllTasks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = Get.find<DataController>();
    super.initState();
  }
...
```

So, you can use `controller` in your widget.

Comment: Hello Guilherme I'm using getx

Comment: Hi! So you can use both options

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared **controller**.

try this.

```
class AllTasks extends StatefullWidget {
  late final controller;
  
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = Get.find<DataController>();
    super.initState();
  }
```